# How to modify pitch of sound file Java?

Tags: java, audio, io, mp3, pitch-shifting

I have a sound file I would like to modify the pitch of. The file is stored in an MP3. I have searched the internet but have been unsuccessful in finding any libraries or algorithms that would allow me to modify the pitch.

Any examples and/or literature would be appreciated

Comment: I can't find an implementation for a byte[]. The solutions I found were with purely sinusoidal waves which I have no idea how to extract from a byte[] or targetDataLine.

Comment: Try searching for soundtouch and java. I am pretty sure there is a java implementation of soundtouch.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not really clear from your question whether you only want to change the playback speed (like the pitch fader on a turntable does) or whether you want to change the pitch without affecting the playback speed. If the latter, you need to use a time stretching/pitch shifting algorithm. See: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Audio_time-scale/pitch_modification

In any case, you'd first have to decode the MP3 into PCM audio. This thread might give you some pointers:

[How to get audio data from a MP3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/938304/how-to-get-audio-data-from-a-mp3)

As for doing pitch shifting in Java, there's some  more info here:

[Slowing down the playback of an audio file without changing its pitch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59936/slowing-down-the-playback-of-an-audio-file-without-changing-its-pitch)