# How to convert male to female or animal voice in android?

Tags: android, voice-recognition, voice

I am working on android voice [application](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.outfit7.mytalkingtomfree&hl=en). I wanted to take my voice and convert it into different voices (female, animal, etc.). I am able to convert my voice in different frequency but it change the frequency of my voice.

I have implemented in change on frequency of voice like this but I don't understand how to convert my voice on same frequency to other voices.

```
public class AndroidAudioRecordActivity extends Activity {

    Integer[] freqset = {11025, 16000, 22050, 44100};
    private ArrayAdapter<Integer> adapter;

    Spinner spFrequency;
    Button startRec, stopRec, playBack;

    Boolean recording;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        startRec = (Button)findViewById(R.id.startrec);
        stopRec = (Button)findViewById(R.id.stoprec);
        playBack = (Button)findViewById(R.id.playback);

        startRec.setOnClickListener(startRecOnClickListener);
        stopRec.setOnClickListener(stopRecOnClickListener);
        playBack.setOnClickListener(playBackOnClickListener);

        spFrequency = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.frequency);
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Integer>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, freqset);
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spFrequency.setAdapter(adapter);

    }

    OnClickListener startRecOnClickListener
    = new OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

            Thread recordThread = new Thread(new Runnable(){

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    recording = true;
                    startRecord();
                }

            });

            recordThread.start();

        }};

    OnClickListener stopRecOnClickListener
    = new OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            recording = false;
        }};

    OnClickListener playBackOnClickListener
        = new OnClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                playRecord();
            }

    };

    private void startRecord(){

        File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "test.pcm"); 

        int sampleFreq = (Integer)spFrequency.getSelectedItem();

        try {
            file.createNewFile();

            OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
            BufferedOutputStream bufferedOutputStream = new BufferedOutputStream(outputStream);
            DataOutputStream dataOutputStream = new DataOutputStream(bufferedOutputStream);

            int minBufferSize = AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize(sampleFreq, 
                    AudioFormat.CHANNEL_CONFIGURATION_MONO, 
                    AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT);

            short[] audioData = new short[minBufferSize];

            AudioRecord audioRecord = new AudioRecord(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC,
                    sampleFreq,
                    AudioFormat.CHANNEL_CONFIGURATION_MONO,
                    AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT,
                    minBufferSize);

            audioRecord.startRecording();

            while(recording){
                int numberOfShort = audioRecord.read(audioData, 0, minBufferSize);
                for(int i = 0; i < numberOfShort; i++){
                    dataOutputStream.writeShort(audioData[i]);
                }
            }

            audioRecord.stop();
            dataOutputStream.close();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    void playRecord(){

        File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "test.pcm");

        int shortSizeInBytes = Short.SIZE/Byte.SIZE;

        int bufferSizeInBytes = (int)(file.length()/shortSizeInBytes);
        short[] audioData = new short[bufferSizeInBytes];

        try {
            InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
            BufferedInputStream bufferedInputStream = new BufferedInputStream(inputStream);
            DataInputStream dataInputStream = new DataInputStream(bufferedInputStream);

            int i = 0;
            while(dataInputStream.available() > 0){
                audioData[i] = dataInputStream.readShort();
                i++;
            }

            dataInputStream.close();

            int sampleFreq = (Integer)spFrequency.getSelectedItem();

            AudioTrack audioTrack = new AudioTrack(
                    AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,
                    sampleFreq,
                    AudioFormat .CHANNEL_CONFIGURATION_MONO,
                    AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT,
                    bufferSizeInBytes,
                    AudioTrack.MODE_STREAM);

            audioTrack.play();
            audioTrack.write(audioData, 0, bufferSizeInBytes);


        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Any answer is appreciable.

Thanks in advance

Comment: By pitching recording. Check out this (in first answer second link) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/59936/slowing-down-the-playback-of-an-audio-file-without-changing-its-pitch

Comment: Please post only *relevant* code. We don't care about your imports. Have a look at http://www.sscce.org.

Comment: Thanks @Niek for reply can u help to solve problem.

Comment: @DjDexter5GHz i visited your link but i can't understand the concept used over there.can u help me what concept basically used over their.

Comment: Use this library in your project, and use documentation to see how to do it. I haven't used it but it should work. http://web.archive.org/web/20081103052639/http://www.adetorres.com/keychanger/KeyChangerReadme.html

Comment: thanks for a nice question your question help me for my startup